# integrating Vraptor 3.5.2 with wildfly

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, vraptor

i'm having some trouble to deploy the blank-project of vraptor 3.5.2 on wildfly 8.2, this only occurs on version 3.5.2 or higher. We have a project that use use vraptor 3.4.*, and for now we can't upgrade for version 4, but we want to use the features of Gson on version 3.5.* , on TomCat the project works perfectly.
Here a piece of the stack that i recieve on wildfly log.

We think the problem is internally of the vraptor, after all we use a clean project. We try to use the latest version of wildfly, but with no success, we also think  the problem could be on the vraptor dependencies libraries, but we change all the libraries to be like the wildfly use, and using tomcat the project still works, but no on wildfly

```
14:18:33,184 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
    14:18:33,247 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-9) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
    14:18:33,372 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
    14:18:33,403 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-13) WELD-000900: 2.2.6 (Final)
    14:18:33,434 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS016008: Starting weld service for deployment hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
    14:18:33,653 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (weld-worker-1) Failed to define class br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.HttpServletRequestProvider in Module "deployment.hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link br/com/caelum/vraptor/ioc/spring/HttpServletRequestProvider (Module "deployment.hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldModuleResourceLoader.classForName(WeldModuleResourceLoader.java:68) [wildfly-weld-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadClass(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:65) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:60) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(FastAnnotatedTypeLoader.java:89) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:97) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:65) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$1.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:62) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            ... 21 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean from [Module "deployment.hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
            at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
            ... 25 more
```

--

```
  Deployment failed: hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: { "outcome" : "failed", "failure-description" : {"JBAS014671: Failed services" : {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" : "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service\n Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:\nException 0 :\norg.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Proxifier with qualifiers @Default\n at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 4 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public br.com.caelum.vraptor.validator.DefaultValidator(Result, ValidationViewsFactory, Outjector, Proxifier, BeanValidator, Localization)\n at br.com.caelum.vraptor.validator.DefaultValidator.(DefaultValidator.java:0)\n\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:372)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:293)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:531)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\nException 0 :\norg.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ExceptionMapper with qualifiers @Default\n at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 3 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultResult(HttpServletRequest, Container, ExceptionMapper, TypeNameExtractor)\n at br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultResult.(DefaultResult.java:0)\n\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:372)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:293)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:531)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)\r\n\tat org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n"}}, "rolled-back" : true }
```